# How to center table with long notes?

Tags: tablenotes

I would like to ask how could I center a Table in the page that contains a lot of notes. I define notes as part of the Table. The code I applied is the following, but the outcome doesn't look nice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{1.\textwidth}{!}{
 \begin{threeparttable}
     \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrr}
 \multicolumn{9}{l}{Table 2: Results}         \\ \hline 

%   &   MEAN    &   STD &   SKEW    &   KURT    &   JBpval  &   AC(1)   \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{9}{l}{Panel A: A}         \\ \hline

A   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
B   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
C   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
D   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
E   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
F   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
G   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
H   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
I   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
J   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
K   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
L   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
M   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
N   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
O   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
Q   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\



 \hline

\multicolumn{9}{l}{Panel B: B}         \\ \hline

A   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
B   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
C   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
D   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
E   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
F   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
G   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
H   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
I   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
J   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
K   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
L   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
M   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
N   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
O   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\
Q   &   -0.00   &   \textbf{0.00}   &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.00**} &   \textbf{0.11}   &   \textbf{0.00*}  &   -0.11   &   \textbf{0.00}   \\ \hline \hline

 \hline
     \end{tabular}
 \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
      \small
      \item Long Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long TextTextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long  Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong  Long  Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong  Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong TextLong Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long TextLong Text Long Text Long Text Long Text ZZZZZZZZ
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide complete, but small document with your table. without knowing your document preamble we cant help you. now is seems that your table is to big for one page, probably you should consider to use `longtable`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: I am not sure how to provide a small document with the table. I am trying to attach the tex file but I can't see that option in the menu bar.

Comment: to your code snippet please add `\docxumentclass{...}, follwing with document preamble (only relevant packages, please) and `\begin{document}` and after your code snippet  `\end{document}` . just edit your question and this missing parts of code add as you insert your table code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I included these parts in the code. I think now it is more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- don't use `\resizebox`
- instead `\begin{center} .... \end{center}`, which introduce additional vertical space, put `\centering` after `\begin{table}`
- consider to use smaller fonts: for table `\small` and for table notes `footnotesize`
- see, if you can change page layout, for example increase `\textheight` and `\textwidth`.

considering the first three items i obtain the following result:

[image]

off-topic:

- code for table can be shorter (if whole column is in bold face, than this can be obtain with

`\begin{tabular}{lrr *{5}>{\bfseries}r} r >{\bfseries}r}`

and omitting all `\textbf{` ... `}` in the table body.

- for table caption you should use capability of `threeparttable` and move caption from `multicolumn` in tabular to caption in `threeparttable`:

```
...
\begin{table}
\small
\centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table 2: Results}         
     \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrr} 
     \hline
%   &   MEAN    &   STD &   SKEW    &   KURT    &   JBpval  &   AC(1)   \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{9}{l}{Panel A: A}         \\ \hline
 ...
```

Comment: i am doing IEEE format but my table only comes in either one column (right column so table gets clipped) or in the appendix overlay where appendix and table appear same time. can you please take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586829/centering-a-table-in-ieee-two-row-format-journal)