# Centering a table in IEEE two column format journal

Tags: tables, two-column, center

I want the table to be centered (occupying both the columns) in two column journal like IEEE. I was able to utilize the following for images:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
  \centering
```

but for table, I was unable to achieve it even if I add `\centering`. What can be done?

```
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{cr rr rr rr rr}
  \toprule % <-- Toprule here

  \textbf{Lorem} &\hspace*{1em}  \textbf{a}& \textbf{b}& \textbf{c}&  \textbf{d} &\hspace*{1.5em}  \textbf{e}\%  &\hspace*{0.1em} \%\\

  \midrule % <-- Midrule here
  lorem & x  & x  & x & x \\
  lorem & x  & x  & x & x \\

  \bottomrule % <-- Bottomrule here
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]    % <---
    \footnotesize
    lorem ipsum; 
 \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
 \end{center}
 \end{footnotesize}
```

Comment: If you want your table to occupy both columns of a two column text, you can use `\begin{table*}\footnotesize\centering` instead of `\begin{footnotesize}\begin{center}
\centering` and `\end{table*}` instead of `\end{center} \end{footnotesize}` . However, your current example table should easily fit into a single column.

Comment: @leandriis I want to add more columns to the table later on. But when I do what you mentioned, the table does center but it appears after appendices section and also not immediately in the beginning of the page, table appears in upper middle of new page after appendices.

Comment: @leandriis I also added   '\begin{table*}[ht]' but no effect whatsoever

Comment: @user0193: Can you provide a *complete*, minimal example that shows the `\documentclass` you're using? Perhaps there's something in your code (or the class) that is causing this.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually show the use of a `table*` environment. For sure, using a simple `center` environment will *not* succeed in creating an object (say, a table) that spans both columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your question is due of lack of information about your document quite unclear. In general you cant have table over two columns over two columns on the first page. It when you not use `stfloats` package appear on the top of the next page from point of insertion, so for `table*` has sense only `tp` positions specifiers.
- With `stfloats` package table can appear also on the bottom of the page where is inserted if you use position specifier `b` and there is enough space for `table˙*` from the point of insertion. If it is not, than will be moved to the bottom of the next page.

Assuming that your document is something like this:

```
\documentclass[journal, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{stfloats}% for placement table on the same page

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text filler

\title{My IEEEtran article}
\author{me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[65]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Broad band networks, quality of service, WDM.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{table*}[b]
  \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{My three part table}
    \label{tab:widetable}
\begin{tabular}{cr rr rr rr rr}
    \toprule % <-- Toprule here
\textbf{Lorem}  & \textbf{a}    & \textbf{b}    & \textbf{c}    
                & \textbf{d}    & \textbf{e}    &               \\
    \midrule % <-- Midrule here
lorem           & xxxx          & xxxx          & xxxx
                & xxxx          & xxxx          & xxxx          \\
lorem           & xxxx          & xxxx          & xxxx
                & xxxx          & xxxx          & xxxx          \\
    \bottomrule % <-- Bottomrule here
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para] \footnotesize
    \note{lorem ipsum}
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}  
\end{table*}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

than you can at the best can get the following result:

[image]

If this is not what you after, than please edit your question, provide complete compilable small document (like this in my answer) and clarify what is your problem. General instruction for use of IEEEtran, you can find in *How to Use the IEEEtran LATEX Class*. It is avaliable on your local installation of IEEEtran or on CTAN (use Google for search).

Comment: Thanks a lot Zarko! I believe the problem I have is that the template although for IEEE publication is not using IEEEtran! I just saw after seeing your document that it is using `\usepackage{apalike}` and using `\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}` so that is why the table is appearing after the References! I will change the styling to IEEEtran! Thanks again